# NodeJS Windows Forever Cluster Issue

Tags: windows, node.js, forever

I have an issue when I call forever module in windows, it works fine except that my code is calling Cluster module , and I do "Cluster.fork()", the problem is that I got 2 empty consoles opened! like the image shows(2 because I have 2 CPUs) and when I close them, they re-open automatically(because of Forever). I also tested forever-win module with the same result. every thing is fine except that I dont want to show those consoles.
Note: I face this in windows only not Ubuntu

[image]

Comment: Could you post the code you are using? Forever should not be aware that you are closing a forked instance. If you start the script without using Forever, do you still get 2 instances?

Comment: @hknust `for (var i = 0; i < numCPUs; i++) {
    cluster.fork();
  }`

the problem just happens in windows not Ubuntu